# Prometheus not exporting Kafka Consumer data upon upgrade from Spring Boot 2.1.6 to 2.2.2

Tags: prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer, spring-micrometer, prometheus-java

We upgraded Spring Boot version from 2.1.6 to 2.2.2. Some of the properties being seen in the **Prometheus** endpoint in 2.1.6 is not visible in 2.2.2.

- `kafka_consumer_records_consumed_total_records_total`
- `kafka_consumer_records_lag_records`
- `kafka_consumer_fetch_latency_max_seconds`
- `kafka_consumer_bytes_consumed_total_bytes_total`

However, this data is being registered in MBeans.

Example for **kafka_consumer_records_consumed_total_records_total**

[image]

Am I missing some configurations? How can I export this data available in MBeans to the actuator endpoint ("`/prometheus`") ?

Update: Prometheus version we are using in both versions is the same.

```
    1.3.1
```

POM.xml (Before the change)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>actuator-demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>actuator-demo</name>
<description>Spring Boot Actuator Demo Project</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Micrometer Prometheus registry  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-wiremock</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

POM.xml (After the change -- Only Spring Boot is upgraded)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>actuator-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>actuator-demo</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Actuator Demo Project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Micrometer Prometheus registry  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-wiremock</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Can you report what the transitive version changes were too? For example what version of Micrometer and Kafka client were before and are now?

Comment: @checketts The version in before and after upgrade is the same.         1.3.2. I've updated the question with the information.

Comment: I've raised a bug for this. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19507

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kafka metrics are using JMX and JMX is disabled by default as of Spring Boot 2.2. You need to enable JMX for Kafka Metrics to work, i.e. `spring.jmx.enabled=true` in your configuration.